# mysql how to add foreign key constraint correctly (error code #1215)

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

It always show that "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint"

This is the color table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_color` (
`color` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
enter code here)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the manufacturer table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_manufacturer` (
`manufacturer` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`icon` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the size table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_size` (
`size` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the status table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_status` (
`status` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the product table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_product` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`manufacturer` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`product` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`color` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`original_price` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`icon` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the item table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_item` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`tag1` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`tag2` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`tag3` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

This is the user table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

I want to add some foreign key.
But it always that: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `manufacturer` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer`) REFERENCES `tb_manufacturer` (`manufacturer`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `size` FOREIGN KEY (`size`) REFERENCES `tb_size` (`size`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `color` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `tb_color` (`color`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tb_user` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `tb_product` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `status` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `tb_status` (`status`);
```

Comment: Make the reference column `Primary Key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following runs thru fine now. The tables with a drop above them needed tweaked with primary keys added (or at least a non-unique key). Otherwise child table depending on it can't look it up for the FK. I tested it.

```
-- drop table tb_color;
CREATE TABLE `tb_color` (
`color` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
primary key (color)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

-- drop table tb_manufacturer;
CREATE TABLE `tb_manufacturer` (
`manufacturer` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`icon` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
primary key (manufacturer)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

-- drop table tb_size;
CREATE TABLE `tb_size` (
`size` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
primary key (size)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

-- drop table tb_status;
CREATE TABLE `tb_status` (
`status` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
primary key(status)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tb_product` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`manufacturer` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`product` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`color` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`original_price` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`icon` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tb_item` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`tag1` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`tag2` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`tag3` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tb_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `manufacturer` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer`) REFERENCES `tb_manufacturer` (`manufacturer`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `size` FOREIGN KEY (`size`) REFERENCES `tb_size` (`size`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_product` ADD CONSTRAINT `color` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `tb_color` (`color`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tb_user` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `tb_product` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tb_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `status` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `tb_status` (`status`);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of foreign key constraint, below points keep in mind-

- both (master/child) columns should have same data type/length.
- column in master table should be indexed.

In your case problem seems that related column in master table is not indexed.